# The prefix “ cannot be redefined from ” to <url> within the same start element tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, namespaces

I am creating an XML file, like the example below and I try to **add** the **first** `xmlns` attribute to the `<feed>` tag but it gives me an error:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
```

Here is the format of the full XML file I try to create:

```
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<title>Glowbox</title>
<link rel="self" href="https://glowbox.gr/"/>
<entry>
 <g:id>
  <![CDATA[ 4248 ]]>
 </g:id>
 <g:mpn>
  <![CDATA[ BLS054 ]]>
 </g:mpn>
 <g:title>
  <![CDATA[ Body Mist Summer Tales ]]>
 </g:title>
 <g:product_type/>
 <g:google_product_category>
  <![CDATA[ ]]>
 </g:google_product_category>
 <g:price>
  <![CDATA[ 13.5 EUR ]]>
 </g:price>
 <g:custom_label_1>
  <![CDATA[ no ]]>
 </g:custom_label_1>
 <g:image_link>
  <![CDATA[ https://glowbox.gr/7798/body-mist-summer-tales.jpg ]]>
 </g:image_link>
 <g:condition>new</g:condition>
 <g:link>
  <![CDATA[
   https://glowbox.gr/home/4248-body-mist-summer-tales.html
  ]]>
 </g:link>
 <g:description>
  <![CDATA[
  Aναζωογονητικό και ενυδατικό mist σώματος με εκχύλισμα αλόης και χαμομηλιού σε καταπληκτικά 
  αρώματα! 
  ]]>
 </g:description>
 <g:brand>
  <![CDATA[ BLUE SCENTS ]]>
 </g:brand>
 <g:availability>
  <![CDATA[ in stock ]]>
 </g:availability>
</entry>
```

My **code** to create a similar XML file with all the tags is this:

```
XDocument xdoc;
        XNamespace gw = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0";
        xdoc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "", ""),
                new XElement("feed", new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"), new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "g", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"),
                        new XElement("title", "Newcult"),
                        new XElement("link", new XAttribute("href", "http://www.newcult.gr"), new XAttribute("rel", "self")),
                            new XElement("entry",
                                new XElement(gw + "id", "<![CDATA[ 1 ]]>"),
                                new XElement(gw + "title", "2"),
                                new XElement(gw + "description", "3"),
                                new XElement(gw + "link", "4"),
                                new XElement(gw + "image_link", "5"),
                                new XElement(gw + "brand", "6"),
                                new XElement(gw + "gender", "7"),
                                new XElement(gw + "product_type", "8"),
                                new XElement(gw + "condition", "new"),
                                new XElement(gw + "availability", "in stock"),
                                new XElement(gw + "price", " EUR"),
                                new XElement(gw + "sale_price", " EUR"),
                                new XElement(gw + "google_product_category", "1")
                            )
                  )
                );
```

But, when I **run** it, it gives me this error for the first `attribute` in `<feed>` tag:

> The prefix "cannot be redefined from" to 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' within the same start element tag

I have tried changing the order of the `attributes`, or to add the attribute later with an `.Add()` method but nothing works.

Any idea on how to solve this error?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving a lot of headaches.  Try this :

```
           string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                "<feed xmlns:gw=\"http://base.google.com/ns/1.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:g=\"http://base.google.com/ns/1.0\">" +
                "</feed>";


            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(header);
            XElement feed = xdoc.Root;
            XNamespace gw = feed.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("gw");
            XNamespace g = feed.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("g");
            XNamespace ns = feed.GetDefaultNamespace();

            feed.Add(new XElement(ns + "title", "Newcult" ),
                    new XElement(ns + "link", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("href", "http://www.newcult.gr"), 
                        new XAttribute("rel", "self"),
                        new XElement(ns + "entry", new object[] {
                            new XElement(gw + "id", "<![CDATA[ 1 ]]>"),
                            new XElement(gw + "title", "2"),
                            new XElement(gw + "description", "3"),
                            new XElement(gw + "link", "4"),
                            new XElement(gw + "image_link", "5"),
                            new XElement(gw + "brand", "6"),
                            new XElement(gw + "gender", "7"),
                            new XElement(gw + "product_type", "8"),
                            new XElement(gw + "condition", "new"),
                            new XElement(gw + "availability", "in stock"),
                            new XElement(gw + "price", " EUR"),
                            new XElement(gw + "sale_price", " EUR"),
                            new XElement(gw + "google_product_category", "1")
                        })
                    })
             );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! You did help me with my problem and I did modify the code a little bit to achieve my goal but now there is a new problem. The tag `<entry>`, now has an attribute `xmlns=""` that I don't want. Below is the XML output. Can you please help me?

`<entry xmlns="">
...
</entry>`

Comment: The Net Library expects the default namespace (with no prefix) to be the last. I've seen issue with exception when it is not the last like in your original code.  Not sure if this bug has been fixed in Net.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when attempting to serialize an XNode after changing an XElement `el`'s Namespace e.g. removing it bytby setting

```
el.Name = XNamespace.None + el.Name.LocalName;
```

(If `el`'s namespace was defined by an `xmlns="{uri}"` attribute, e.g. `<element xmlns="{uri}" />`.)

One solution I found in this case was to also remove the XAttribute namespace declaration.

```
el.Attributes("xmlns").Remove();
```

(Or similar, be aware that this additional line does not change the actual namespace of any elements, but it may change how the namespaces are declared in the document.)

The problem seems to occur because .Net XML serializers are "not smart enough" to handle (changed) namespaces in some situations where namespace declarations are explicitly present in the XElement as XAttribute (this is the case when an XNode was deserialized from an XML that contains namespace declarations).